# Pictures in an html website of a spring Boot project arent shown on localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, macos, spring-boot

I have a spring Boot project in eclipse on macos, when i run this project (as a spring Boot Application), and in my webrowser(firefox, edge and safari) i see all the Elements of this page, but not the picture i inserted in this page, so what is the problem??

Comment: Could you add some details about your controllers and how you add pictures to your page (code)?

Comment: i use thymleaf in this project, the image is placed in this way in the project            
/securing-web/src/main/resources/static/img/gruenerHintergrund.png                              
i use in html this peace of code to point to this picture                                                 <img th:src="@{/img/gruenerHintergrund.png}" alt="gruenerHintergrund.png"/> but in localhost:8080 on all of my Webbrowsers,  it does not show this picture

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration
public class DefaultView extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers( ViewControllerRegistry registry ) {
    registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "forward:/yourpage.html" );
    registry.setOrder( Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE );
    super.addViewControllers( registry );
}
```

}

Comment: i add this class DefaultView  to my project with exactly the same code you mean it with your comment, but the image is doesnt show, for the path i wrote the path of my Website that i found with right click on my website ( in my  folder Structure ) and then properties i have a  public class named "WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{"